# How to make that at least one radio button must be checked, if it's not, don't allow user to go to next question?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my quiz. It's generated directly in JS and I don't know how to make this work.

I tried some JS funcions, but none of them worked for me

```
var quiz = [{
  "question": "otazka1",
  "choices": ["nespravne1", "nespravne2", "spravne", "nespravne3"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }, {
  "question": "otazka2",
  "choices": ["spravne", "nespravne1", "nespravne2", "nespravne3"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }, {
  "question": "otazka3",
  "choices": ["nespravne1", "nespravne2", "spravne", "nespravne3"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }, {
  "question": "otazka4",
  "choices": ["nespravne1", "nespravne2", "spravne", "nespravne3"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }, {
  "question": "otazka5",
  "choices": ["nespravne1", "spravne", "nespravne2", "nespravne3"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }, {
  "question": "otazka6",
  "choices": ["nespravne1", "nespravne2", "nespravne3", "spravne"],
  "correct": "spravne"
 }];

var content = $("content"),
questionContainer = $("question"),
choicesContainer = $("choices"),
scoreContainer = $("score"),
submitBtn = $("submit");

 // init vars
var cQarr = [];
for (var i=0; i<quiz.length; i++) { cQarr[i] = i; } // create sequence 
and
for (var i=0; i<cQarr.length; i++) {                // scramble order
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*cQarr.length);
  var tmp = cQarr[rnd];  cQarr[rnd] = cQarr[i]; cQarr[i] = tmp;
}
var currentQuestion = 0,
score = 0,
askingQuestion = true;

function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById
return document.getElementById(id);
}

function askQuestion() {
 var choices = quiz[cQarr[currentQuestion]].choices,
  choicesHtml = "";

 // loop through choices, and create radio buttons
 for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
 choicesHtml += "<input type='radio' name='quiz" + currentQuestion +
   "' id='choice" + (i + 1) +
   "' value='" + choices[i] + "'>" +
   " <label for='choice" + (i + 1) + "'>" + choices[i] + "</label><br>";
  }

  // load the question
  questionContainer.textContent = "Otazka " + (currentQuestion + 1) + ". 
  " +
   quiz[cQarr[currentQuestion]].question;

  // load the choices
  choicesContainer.innerHTML = choicesHtml;

  // setup for the first time
  if (currentQuestion === 0) {
    scoreContainer.textContent = "Skore: 0 spravnych  " +
      quiz.length + " z moznych.";
    submitBtn.textContent = "Potvrdit odpoved";
  }
  }

 function checkAnswer() {
  // are we asking a question, or proceeding to next question?
  if (askingQuestion) {
  submitBtn.textContent = "Dalsia otazka";
   askingQuestion = false;

  // determine which radio button they clicked
  var userpick,
  correctIndex,
  radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) { // if this radio button is checked
  userpick = radios[i].value;
  }

  // get index of correct answer
  if (radios[i].value == quiz[cQarr[currentQuestion]].correct) {
   correctIndex = i;
  }
   }  

  // setup if they got it right, or wrong
  var labelStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("label") 
  [correctIndex].style;
  labelStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
  if (userpick == quiz[cQarr[currentQuestion]].correct) {
    score++;
    labelStyle.color = "green";
  } else {
    labelStyle.color = "red";
   }

  scoreContainer.textContent = "Skore: " + score + " spravna odpoved " +
   quiz.length + " z moznych.";
    } else { // move to next question
     // setting up so user can ask a question
    askingQuestion = true;
     // change button text back to "Submit Answer"
      submitBtn.textContent = "Potvrdit odpoved";
      // if we're not on last question, increase question number
      if (currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1) {
     currentQuestion++;
     askQuestion();
    } else {
     showFinalResults();
  }
 }
}
```

I need it to check if there is one radio button checked and if not, tell the user to check one and don't allow him to move to the next question.

Comment: Could you explain better?  Point out the actual error, which function does not work, where, ...?  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If no question is selected just add an handler or alert accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  "use strict";

  var questions = [{
    question: "What is defined in physics as 'a nuclear reaction in which nuclei combine to form more massive nuclei'?",
    choices: ['fission', 'fusion', 'farking', 'fracking', 'freaking'],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What is the capital of Australia?",
    choices: ["Melbourne", "Sydney", "Canberra", "Queensland", "Christchurch"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }, {
    question: "Who is the prime minister of the U.K.?",
    choices: ['Tony Blair', 'David Cameron', 'Nicolas Sarkozy', 'Gordon Brown', 'Sir John Major'],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What is the first perfect number?",
    choices: [38, 6, 0, 256, 28],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What colors are on the flag of Norway?",
    choices: ["red and blue", "red and white", "red, white, and silver", "red, white, and blue", "blue and gold"],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "When did the Soviet Union collapse?",
    choices: ["14 February 1989", "1 January 1988", "31 October 1993", "26 April 1986", "26 December 1991"],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is the currency of Switzerland?",
    choices: ["franc", "Euro", "rupee", "won", "dollar"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is the square root of 256?",
    choices: [24, 25, 30, 26, 22],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What are the three main types of rocks?",
    choices: ['igneous, volcanic, quartz', 'sedimentary, igneous, metamorphic', 'feldspar, metamorphic, sedimentary', 'gargantuan, feldspar, quartz', 'None of the above'],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What movie did Leonardo DiCaprio win a BAFTA Film Award for?",
    choices: ['Inception', "What's Eating Gilbert Grape", 'The Revenant', 'The Wolf of Wall Street', 'He never got one.'],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }
  ];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('.content'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      $('#warning').text('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
      $('#warning').text('');
    }
  });



  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);
    // this is new
    var warningText = $('<p id="warning">');
    qElement.append(warningText);

    return qElement;

  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
       }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<h3>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
    // Calculate score and display relevant message
    var percentage = numCorrect / questions.length;
    if (percentage >= 0.9){
        score.append('Incredible! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right!');
    }

    else if (percentage >= 0.7){
        score.append('Good job! You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right!');
    }

    else if (percentage >= 0.5){
        score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' questions right.');
    }

    else {
        score.append('You only got ' + numCorrect + ' out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right. Want to try again?');
    }
    return score;
  }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle.
  https://jsfiddle.net/raghulramkish/1wfr3em2/

Comment: I can see that's working, but I tried to implement it to my code and it's not working for me